# How can I use component in Quasar UMD?

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar

I use Quasar UMD in Laravel blade,

I want to use chart in my project

this is an example to use apexcharts in vuejs:

```
  <div id="chart">
    <apexchart type="line" height="350" :options="chartOptions" :series="series"></apexchart>
  </div>
  new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    components: {
      apexchart: VueApexCharts,
    },
    data: {
      
      series: [{
          name: "Desktops",
          data: [10, 41, 35, 51, 49, 62, 69, 91, 148]
      }],
      chartOptions: {
        chart: {
          height: 350,
          type: 'line',
          zoom: {
            enabled: false
          }
        },
        dataLabels: {
          enabled: false
        },
        stroke: {
          curve: 'straight'
        },
        title: {
          text: 'Product Trends by Month',
          align: 'left'
        },
        grid: {
          row: {
            colors: ['#f3f3f3', 'transparent'], // takes an array which will be repeated on columns
            opacity: 0.5
          },
        },
        xaxis: {
          categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep'],
        }
      },
```

But I dont know how can I integrate it with Quasar:
My code in Quasar is:

```
const { ref,computed } = Vue
const app = Vue.createApp({
  setup () {
      const sumOfCalories = computed(() => {
        return rows[0]['calories'] + rows[1]['calories'];
      })

    return {
      onRowClick: (row) => alert(`${row.name} clicked`),
      columns,sumOfCalories,
      rows: ref(rows)
    }
  }
})

app.use(Quasar, { config: {} })
app.mount('#q-app')
```

I link to cdn script of apexcharts, How can I set compoentn in Quasar:

```
components: {
  apexchart: VueApexCharts,
},
```